# Using get_option() in JavaScript

Tags: shortcode, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, options

Previously, I used the `get_option()` function to get an option in PHP, like this:

```
$width = get_option('my_width');
```

This is inside a shortcode function.

Now, I want to have an option in JavaScript. Is that possible?

The JS is added with `wp_enqueue_script`, from a shortcode function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define an array of parameters to be injected into the script:

```
$script_params = array(
    'myWidth' => get_option('my_width')
);
```

Localize the script via [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
wp_localize_script( 'your-script-handle', 'scriptParams', $script_params );
```

`scriptParams` now is a js object you can access from within the script:

```
alert( scriptParams.myWidth ); // the value from the PHP get_option call in the js
```

Comment: Remember you have to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and insert in there the `wp_localize_script` logic.

Comment: Anyone know where this code should go?

Comment: This is my current approach for reading / writing options for a Gutenberg block. I localize the client script with the saved options and use those as default values for my InspectorControls controls. I then rewrite the options in the ServerSideRender callback. However I'm having trouble with the responses becoming too large, and would like to look into handling everything from the client side code: but I'm guessing there is no javascript API for options or transients?

Answer (score 6):

Building on the accepted answer and filling in some details...

You need to call `wp_localize script` right after `wp_enqueue_script`.  So, something like this:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myjs',
        plugins_url( 'js/my.js', __FILE__)
    );

    $options = get_option( 'my_settings' );

    $scriptData = array(
        'width' => $options['my_width'],
    );

    wp_localize_script('myjs', 'my_options', $scriptData);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Then, as the accept answer shows, my_options is now a JavaScript object.

```
alert( my_options.width );
```

The way that this works is that `wp_localise_script` embeds some JavaScript in the HTML of the page, right before including your script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var my_options = {"width":"42"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/js/myjs.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

So that's how send data from PHP on a server to JavaScript in a browser via HTML using WordPress.  Clever, hey?

(Aside: I had a problem where $options wasn't defined.  I thought it was because the queuing was happening before $options was defined [as the WP docs mention](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script#Notes). So I had my script loading in the footer using the in_footer argument of wp_enqueue_script (which means the localization data would be there too).  Later, I moved it back to the header to see if that was really a problem, and everything was still working.  So, beware.).

If it seems like a hack to be using something called `wp_localize_script`, note that the [WordPress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) say that what we're doing is completely acceptable:

> Though localization is the primary use, it can be used to make any
>   data available to your script that you can normally only get from the
>   server side of WordPress.